# How to get symbol info from semantic model in roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to create a code analyzer in Roslyn, and I need to analyze SqlCommand usage in a project. I have written the analyzer and it works fine when I test it out in Visual Studio project, but when I am writing unit test and I am trying to get `SymbolInfo` from `SemanticModel` and am always getting null.

What am i missing?

```
string test = @"public class TestClass
                {
                    public void SomeMethod(int x)
                    {
                        var command = new SqlCommand(""Some COmmabnd"",new SqlConnection(""conn string""));
                        command.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                }";

var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(test);
var systemDataReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Data.IDbCommand).Assembly.Location);
var systemConfigurationReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ConfigurationManager).Assembly.Location);
var systemTransactionReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Transaction).Assembly.Location);
var systemXmlnReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(XPathDocument).Assembly.Location);
var system = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location);
var mscorRef = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var systemCore  = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location);
var systemNumerics = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(BigInteger).Assembly.Location);

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("TestCompilatin", new[] {tree},
    new[]
    {
        mscorRef, system, systemXmlnReference, systemTransactionReference, systemDataReference,
        systemConfigurationReference,systemCore,systemNumerics
    });

var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

var invocationExpressions = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
foreach (var invocationExpressionSyntax in invocationExpressions)
{
   var memeber = invocationExpressionSyntax.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
    var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memeber);

}
```

`semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo()` returns `SymbolInfo` with null symbol for anything that I try.

Comment: Check for compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks I missed adding the using statements. I was expecting roslyn compilation to throw error, looks like I was wrong.

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti How did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that the source file for the invoked method has not been syntactically parsed and added to the compilation. You can always get some information about the method being invoked in the caller's syntax tree, but unless the invoked method has already been added to the compilation, it won't be available in the semantic model. This is painfully obvious after thinking about it for a bit. Of course the semantic model will not have information about a method that has not been processed. It is possible to add multiple syntax trees to a single compilation using AddSyntaxTrees() method. Note that this method returns a **new** compilation instance.

Hopefully this will save someone a little bit of time and I haven't embarrassed myself too much by posting this answer.